# RHEL choosing java with alternatives without --config

Tags: linux, debian, java, redhat-enterprise-linux

A machine on which there is already the following packages installed:

```
java-1.7.0-openjdk
java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless
```

I have also then installed `java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless` via yum.

When installing the new package, alternatives defaults to the 1.8.0 version of java (which is fine).

I can change this with `alternatives --config java` which prompts with:

```
There is 3 program that provides 'java'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
   1           /usr/java/jre1.8.0_161/bin/java
 + 2           java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.231-2.6.19.1.el7_6.x86_64/jre/bin/java)
*  3           java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222.b10-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre/bin/java)
```

However, if I want to change this without the prompt to 1.7 and/or back to 1.8, using `alternatives --set ...` I need to know the specific minor version/build information of java, e.g. `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222.b10-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre/bin/java` which seems a bit counter intuitive since I installed the package by only specifying the major version (`1.8.0`). And I'm unclear how I could achieve this in an automated way or with something like Ansible...

Looking at the symlinks that get created in `/usr/lib/jvm` there are the following:

```
java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.221-2.6.18.0.el7_6.x86_64
java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.231-2.6.19.1.el7_6.x86_64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222.b10-0.el7_6.x86_64
jre -> /etc/alternatives/jre
jre-1.7.0 -> /etc/alternatives/jre_1.7.0
jre-1.7.0-openjdk -> /etc/alternatives/jre_1.7.0_openjdk
jre-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.231-2.6.19.1.el7_6.x86_64 -> java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.231-2.6.19.1.el7_6.x86_64/jre
jre-1.8.0 -> /etc/alternatives/jre_1.8.0
jre-1.8.0-openjdk -> /etc/alternatives/jre_1.8.0_openjdk
jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222.b10-0.el7_6.x86_64 -> java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222.b10-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre
jre-openjdk -> /etc/alternatives/jre_openjdk
```

Which suggests that the intention is to specify the long form of the java version on RHEL.

On Debian based systems, the path is helpfully something along the lines of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java`.

Is there something I'm missing here? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question, based on help from #centos on irc.freenode.net, to select/set on the command line:

```
# alternatives --set java java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64
```

For Ansible, looking at the source of the `alternatives` module it requires a path to the java executable, such as `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222.b10-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre/bin/java` so this doesn't seem to be as easy/straight forward.

Comment: I've added a feature request for the alternatives Ansible package to support this: https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/issues/5060